# How to query RTC builds?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, rtc, rational-team-concert

We are using RTC for version control and build system.
RTC's web interface allow user to create custom queries for work items - good.

How about creating custom queries to the builds (or other RTC items maybe)?
Let's say I want to know in what builds this particular file was modified or in what builds this particular team member contributed something.

Definitely there is no web interface to do this.
Maybe some other tool? .. Something...

BTW, I didn't find it in scm.exe tool provided with eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no web GUI for building such a query, there is a REST API for querying Build Results:

See "[Report REST API](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ReportsRESTAPI#build)" (you need a -- free -- jazz.net account to access it), for `com.ibm.team.build.BuildResult`, that you can access [as in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/133095/i-need-help-with-rtc-rest-api?redirect=/forum/questions/133095/i-need-help-with-rtc-rest-api), for instance:

```
https://<host>:<port>/jazz/resource/itemOid/com.ibm.team.build.BuildResult/_uKcncTTuEeOy2d_WN7u_Bg
```